# AzureFunctionapp APPSETTING_ getting appended

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-keyvault

I have a .net core 2.0 Azure function app, and i have a Keyvault initializer code which fetches values from keyvault and assigns to a ConcurrentDictionary, the functionality works fine, but i see lot of dependency failures for each of the keyvault URI settings. 
My guess is APPSETTING_ is getting appended to each of the setting values. My code logic is reading all Environment variables and trying to find out what all settings contain Keyvault domain address, for those values i am making a call to Keyvault API to resolve the values.

**Code:**

```
        var envVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var retryInstance = RetryHelper.Instance;
        SecretBundle secretBundle = new SecretBundle();

        var keyVaultAddress = ConfigurationHelper.GetEnvironmentVariables("KeyVaultBaseUrl");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyVaultAddress))
        {
            foreach (string envKey in envVar.Keys)
            {
                string envValue = envVar[envKey].ToString();

                //Check if previously the values have been added to the dictionary or not
                if (envValue.Contains(Constants.VAULT) && envValue.Contains(Constants.HTTPS) && !KeyVaultValues.ContainsKey(envKey))
                {
                    retryInstance.RetryAction( () =>
                    {
                        secretBundle = KeyVaultInitializer.GetValuesFromKeyvault(envKey,
                        keyVaultAddress).Result;
                    }, Constants.MAXRETRIES, Constants.WAITBETWEENRETRY, RetryHelper.BackOffStrategy.Linear);

                    if (secretBundle != null && secretBundle.Value != null )
                        KeyVaultValues.TryAdd(envKey, secretBundle.Value);
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            //TODO: Log failure event
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know there's already a configuration provider for key-vault? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0  There's also the soon to be GA key-vault references feature? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i am aware of it, but i want to know where that error is getting logged in the telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `envKey` to `KeyVaultInitializer.GetValuesFromKeyvault`, surely you'd want to use the value of the setting, not the key?

Comment: That's what I thought at first but it looks like they are using the value as a flag to say "fetch this key from key-vault". Odd.

Comment: The idea is, if any keys are added in keyvault it should get picked automatically by teh function app, and loaded into a concurrent dictionary. There is no problem with this code. I am trying to figure out why Appsetting_ is getting automatically appended to the current Appsettings values for the azure function app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "_" in a secret name.

> An object-name is a user provided name for and must be unique within a
>   Key Vault. The name must be a 1-127 character string, containing only
>   0-9, a-z, A-Z, and -.

Comment: I have not marked _ my secrets are user provided names, APPSETTING_ is appended to the secrets from somewhere (azure function app or something) i am trying to figure out where these are coming from. It makes a get call to my keyvault with wrong secrets and creates noise in the telemetry.